# Programmatically adding/updating web services references using a user form

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013

At the moment I just follow the tutorial to add web services (non-native/non.net) using the wizard.

[image]

Which creates following code in web.config file.

```
<applicationSettings>
        <cart_Test.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="cart_Test_net_webservicex_www_globalweather" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </cart_Test.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Also it can be seen in `Properties.Settings` form. When I updated the Properties.Settings, I see that Web.Config file is also updated. But when deleting this web service from properties.settings, it was only removed from web.config file and I could see the web service hanging there in the solution explorer under the `web references`.

I want to add/update/delete the service entirely from the application programmatically, to say that taking an input from the user and then access the properties.settings and update/add web service when web application is setting up/installing.

So when publishing and packaging the application, it would be quite user friendly to allow admin to add web services using a custom settings-form  instead of messing up with the back-end code.

How can I approach this?

Comment: You need to add a reference to ANY webservice or just update the endpoint for a specific one?

Comment: @RubensFarias Well I want to add new web services, replace/update/delete current ones. As of now, most likely it's just updating the web service URL value. But I am not sure why this updating value didn't delete the old one from web references though. Also, there's no way to add this to the database. Database is *untouchable* :)